# How to load version number in angular (v4+) app from package.json?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, systemjs

I am trying to load the version number of my Angular application from package.json because that is where the version number is located. When looking up how to do this, most people suggest using require to load the json file like:

```
var pckg = require('../../package.json');
console.log(pckg.version);
```

When I put this code in the constructor of a component, I get undefined.

Next I try putting the require statement above the component by the imports like:

```
const { version: appVersion } = require('../../package.json')

export class StackOverflowComponent {
  public appVersion

  constructor() {
    this.appVersion = appVersion
  }
}
```

and I get *Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token :* when the require is trying to parse the json file. When I hover over require I see that it is of type "NodeRequire(id: string)". Is this different than requirejs?

I am using systemjs and I noticed a lot of people with answers are referring to Webpack. Here are relevant files that may help you answer my problem.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
   "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

devDependencies in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "rollup": "^0.50.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^8.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you've encountered is that SystemJS is trying to interpret a JSON file as if it were executable. In order to get SystemJS to load JSON files sensibly, you need to use a JSON loader like [`systemjs-plugin-json`](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-json).

You need to make it available in your SystemJS configuration. For instance, I use:

```
SystemJS.config({
  paths: {
    // Set an abbreviation to avoid having to type /node_modules/ all the time.
    "npm:": "/node_modules/",
    // ....
  },
  map: {
    // The loader is known to SystemJS under the name "json".
    json: "npm:systemjs-plugin-json",
    // ...
  },
  packageConfigPaths: [
    // Tell SystemJS that it should check the package.json files 
    // when figuring out the entry point of packages. If you omit this, then
    // the map above would have to be "npm:systemjs-plugin-json/json.js".
    "npm:*/package.json",
    // ...
  ],
});
```

Then you need to use it. You could replace your `require` call with `require('../../package.json!json');` but I suspect that TypeScript would not be happy with this due to the funky module name. The `!json` part tells SystemJS to use the `json` loader. I never do this. Instead, I set a `meta` in my configuration that tells SystemJS, "use the `json` loader when you load this file":

```
SystemJS.config({
  meta: {
    "path/to/package.json": {
      loader: "json",
    },
  },
});
```

You need to figure out `path/to/package.json` on the basis of the rest of your SystemJS configuration, `baseUrl` in particular.

Comment: This worked for local development. However, now on my AOT compilation I am getting *Cannot find module '../../package.json'.*

Comment: Are you doing to AoT build through Webpack? And is it Webpack giving you that error?

Comment: Actually, that error occured  in AOT compilation when I used *import * as pkg from '../../package.json';* When I used *var pckg = require('../../package.json');* this worked in local development, and compiled in AOT with rollup, but then when I load the site I get *Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at build.js:1*

Comment: I'd expect rollup to take care of that `require` call for you, in the same way Webpack would do. However, I'm not familiar with rollup. You may want to search this site to see if there's already a Q&A that answers your issue, and if not then ask a new question. Even though you're working on the same project as for this question, Building an Angular project for JiT and building it for AoT are two very different ballgames, that often require significantly different strategies. So asking a different question is warranted.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the following to your typings.d.ts :

```
declare module '*.json' {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

you can then do this:

```
import * as pkg from '../path-to-root/package.json';
```

and later refer to it like this, e.g. in you component's constructor:

```
 console.log(`version: ${pkg['version']}`);
```

or, equivalently,

```
console.log(`version: ${(<any>pkg).version}`);
```

Comment: I saw this too. Unfortunately, this produces the same error *Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token :
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :*.  Using this method, when the typescript is compiled into javascript, the javascript is still using require. that line is compiled into: *var pkg = require("../../package.json");*

Comment: works ok for me, with angular 4.4.4, typescript 2.3.3

Comment: This is not the solution. The error message is not a compilation error but a loading error. SystemJS tries to execute the JSON and chokes. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47167168/1906307).

Comment: Ah... I missed the fact that you're using systemjs